# Why it is complaining `declaration has type inferred from a platform call` in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why it is complaining `declaration has type inferred from a platform call`
when the method which is in java is annotated with NotNull annotation. 
I would expect this warning in case if the java method is not annotated with NotNull annotation 
code in Kotlin

```
 override fun getOverlay() =  createDefaultOverlay(context)
```

and code in java

```
   @NonNull
    public static RecyclerView createRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {}
```

Comment: Which `NotNull` annotation are you using? IOW, what is its fully-qualified class name?

Comment: @javax.annotation.Nonnull

Comment: If I am interpreting [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#jsr-305-support) correctly, you would need to use `@NonNull(when = When.ALWAYS)`.

Comment: Yes, it is what we are using. but in that case why the compiler complains ?

Comment: "it is what we are using" -- not according to your question. Your question just has `@NonNull`. My expectation is that this would default to `@NonNull(when = When.UNKNOWN)`, which according to the Kotlin documentation would give you the symptoms that you are experiencing.

Comment: Actually we have our own annotations for some reasons that is referring to @NonNull(when = When.Always). sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: And the default one is  actually When.Always and in our project we specify When.Always.

Comment: So that is why I am wondering why it should refer It as platform type

Comment: "we have our own annotations for some reasons that is referring to @NonNull(when = When.Always)" -- so that is now two significant differences between your real code and the code in the question. :-( Try somewhere using `@NonNull(when = When.ALWAYS)` directly. Does it give you what you are looking for? If yes, then there is a bug/limitation in the IDE inspection that is not handling your annotations that are referring to `@NonNull`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I directly added NonNull annotation and now the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: Please add your comment as answer I will vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@NonNull(when = When.ALWAYS)` should tell Kotlin that the Java code is returning a non-`null` value.

In your case, you were not using `@NonNull(when = When.ALWAYS)` directly, but instead had some other custom annotation that applied `@NonNull(when = When.ALWAYS)`. Apparently, there is a bug or limitation in the IDE inspections for nullability that do not handle this case. If you can create a reproducible sample project, consider filing a bug report.